# install Windows virtual machine on Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, command-line-interface, virtual-machines

How to install a Windows XP or Windows Server 2003 virtual machine on a remote Ubuntu server by command line?

Also, please advise what virtualization software is best for this kind of job?

Comment: Please be more specific, what virtualization software are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes you are using VirtualBox, which is free and available for Linux as well as other operating systems:

Create the virtual machine on another computer first, and install windows the normal way. Once the virtual machine is configured the way you want it, transfer the virtual disk image to the remote ubuntu machine.

Once you have the image in place, you can control virtualbox from a command line using the VBoxManage command. For example, to start a VM called "WinXP" you issue a command like:

$ VBoxManage startvm "WinXP" -type vrdp.

Comment: Does the computer on which WinXP is installed need to be exactly same in configs as the remote server?

Comment: @jack - no: the virtual machine handles that level of abstraction for you